# Servicem8 and webhooks

Tags: webhooks

I was able to get jobactivities to fire when they are created, however I cannot seem to hook into jobactivities when they are updated or deleted.

I have this in my manifest:

```
    "oauth": {
    "scope": "manage_schedule read_schedule"
},
"actions": [],
"menuItems": [],
"webhooks": [{
    "object": "jobactivity",
    "fields": [
        "activity_was_scheduled", "uuid", "start_date", "end_date", "has_been_opened", "edit_date"
    ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you interested in being notified for booking cancellations, subscribe to the 'active' field. Otherwise if you're interested in booking schedule changes, subscribe to start_date + end_date should do the trick.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.